# Waiting for executor Service thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class which uses the executor service to run a task concurrently.

Code:

```
class SomeClass{
private static ExecutorService taskThread = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1, new ThreadFactory() {
        private int threadCount = 0;

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        }
    });

    static {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                taskThread.shutdown();
            }
        });
    }


doSomeTask()
{
            DocumentUploader callable = new DocumentUploader(randomID,fileLoc);         
            FutureTask<String> task1 = new FutureTask<String>(callable);
            taskThread.execute(task1);
}


someFunctionforWait(){


//what here..???
}
```

I have another class name `SomeOtherClass` which will access the modifications / calculations done by `task1` thread. So I need to wait for the thread to complete, So how can I wait for `task1` to complete . What I intend to do is to call `someFunctionforWait()` from the class `SomeOtherClass` to check if the thread has completed and then start to do its task.

How do I do that.

Comment: ExecutorService shutdown and awaitTermination

Comment: could you please ellaborate more ..? where should i put those in sumFunctionWait() ..? @emsworth

Answer (score 1):

You could use Futures, or if you want to stick with the ExecutorService, just wait for taskThread.shutdown() and taskThread.awaitTermination(); you could put those statements into your someFunctionforWait() and continue execution after that.  Here is a simplified example based on your code:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private ExecutorService taskThread = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    private List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
    void doSomeTask() {
        FutureTask<String> task1 = new FutureTask<String>(new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("thread executing");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                return Thread.currentThread().toString();
            }
        });
        taskThread.execute(task1);
        futures.add(task1);
    };

    public void someFunctionforWait() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
        taskThread.shutdown();
        taskThread.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("joined");
    }

    public void someFunctionforWaitAlternative() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
        for(Future<String> future : futures) {
            System.out.println("future val: " + future.get());
        }
        System.out.println("joined");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SomeClass c = new SomeClass();
        c.doSomeTask();
        c.someFunctionforWait();
        //c.someFunctionforWaitAlternative();
    }
}
```

Comment: someFunctionforWait never gives you the result of the Callable

Comment: @Jean Logeart It doesn't necessarily have to - it wasn't really specified in the original question.  But you are right, that is a difference between the two.  If you wanted to store the results using Runnable/shutdown/awaitTermination, a thread-safe mechanism to store the results of execution would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) through `taskThread` and call [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) on it. It will block until the `Future` is completed:

```
Future<String> f = taskThread.submit(callable); // concurrent operation
String result = f.get();   // blocks until f completes
// use result
```